# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (React, heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

found this error on my heroku deployment but working fine on my local setup
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Further the sample code is given as:

```
articles=[];
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        articles: [],
        loading: true,
        page: 0,
        totalResults:0
        };
}
fetchMoreData=async ()=>{
        console.log("Fetch More")   
        let url=`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=${this.props.apiKey}&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
        let data = await fetch(url);
        let parsedData = await data.json();
        this.setState({
            page:this.state.page+1,
            articles : this.state.articles.concat(parsedData.articles),
            totalResults:parsedData.totalResults
        })
    }
render(){
   return(<InfiniteScroll dataLength={this.state.articles.length} next={this.fetchMoreData} hasMore={this.state.articles.length!==this.state.totalResults} loader={<Spinner/>}>
{this.state.articles.map((ele)=>{
     return(
     <div className="col-lg-4 my-3" key={ele.url?ele.url:"/"}>
<NewsItem 
    title={ele.title?ele.title:" "} 
    description={ele.description?ele.description.slice(0,90):" "} 
    img_url={ele.urlToImage?ele.urlToImage:"https://c.ndtvimg.com/2022- 
    06/jlikupmg_virat-kohli-806_625x300_22_June_22.jpg"} 
    newsUrl={ele.url?ele.url:"/"} 
    author={ele.author?ele.author:"Anonymous"} 
    date={ele.publishedAt} source={ele.source.name}/>    
</div>)
})}
)}
```

Comment: What do you see when you console log this.state.articles?

Comment: The JSON of the articles fetched by the api